# Getting user owned pages using Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I need to retrieve all the pages owned by the current user. I need the syntax. Can it be done using Graph API???

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Use the `/me/accounts` path.

Comment: You request it in the `scope` when your user logs in. See here for a description: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/login/

Comment: yes sir i have added that as manage_pages.. but then i still don get anything displayed. @cpilko